# Time constrained optimization?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve a maximization problem that apparently is too complicated (it's a convex function) and NMaximize just runs endlessly.

I'd like to have an approximate result, though. How can I tell `NMaximize` to just give up after $n$ seconds and give me the best it has found so far?

Comment: There's `MaxIterations`, but it's not a constraint based on time.

Comment: I have often wanted such an option

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I usually deal with this kind of problem. Keywords to the solution are `TimeConstrained`, `AbortProtect`, `Throw` and `Catch`.

Consider the two target functions:

```
fun[x_] := (Pause[1]; x^4 - 3 x^2 - x);
fun2[x_, y_] := (Pause[1]; x + y);
```

Now we define our own optimization routine, that is `TimeConstrained` by some `timeLimit`.

```
timedOptimization[timeLimit_, vars_, target_, constraints___] :=
  Module[{objective, bestVal = 100, symbolicVars = HoldForm /@ vars, tempVal},
   objective[v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ]] := Module[{val}, 
     val = target@@v; If[val < bestVal, bestVal = val; tempVal = ReleaseHold@v;];
     val
     ];
   AbortProtect[Catch@TimeConstrained[
      NMinimize[
       {objective[vars],constraints},
       vars,
       MaxIterations -> 400
      ],
      timeLimit,
      Print["Too slow! Aborting with value ", bestVal, " for parameter ", Thread[symbolicVars -> tempVal]]; 
      Throw[{bestVal, Flatten[Thread[symbolicVars -> tempVal]]}]
      ]
    ]
   ];
```

This should be quite clear. Mainly, `AbortProtect` is needed to protect against the `Abort` generated by `TimeConstrained` as soon as `timeLimit` is reached. The current best value and the parameter is `Throw`n within the fail expression for `TimeConstrained` and the outer `Catch` is needed to, well, catch these values.

Due to the `BlankNullSequence`, `constraints` is an optional argument which does not need to be specified. `vars`is a list with all parameters, even if it is a single one. See below examples of how to use with one/multiple arguments and with/without constraints. Please note that the `MaxIterations` option is actually not needed and just included for demonstration purposes (it exists).

```
AbsoluteTiming@timedOptimization[10, {x}, fun]
```

> Too slow! Aborting with value -2.8916 for parameter x->0.965034
>
> {10.001186, {-2.8916, x -> 0.965034}}

```
AbsoluteTiming@timedOptimization[10, {x}, fun, x > 1]
```

> Too slow! Aborting with value -3.24616 for parameter {x->1.09146}
>
> {10.001160, {-3.24616, {x -> 1.09146}}}

```
AbsoluteTiming@timedOptimization[10, {x,y}, fun2]
```

> Too slow! Aborting with value -0.672799 for parameter {x->-0.535769,y->-0.13703}
>
> {10.000125, {-0.672799, {x -> -0.535769, y -> -0.13703}}}

```
AbsoluteTiming@timedOptimization[10, {x,y}, fun2, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

> Too slow! Aborting with value -0.70015 for parameter {x->-0.351705,y->-0.348445}
>   {10.000125, {-0.70015, {x -> -0.351705, y ->-0.348445}}}

Comment: Okay, I like where this is going. How would I add multiple variables and constraints? Also, in the `If` statement, wouldn't it make more sense to say `If[val<bestVal,...]`?

Comment: @Ziofil Right, indeed there was a typo in the `If` statement. With respect to the rest, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Great! Do you also mean  `val = target[v]` and `fun2[{x_,y_}]:=...`?

Comment: @Ziofil Glad I could help. Thanks again for pointing out the mistake again. I should copy-paste the whole notebook after editing it instead of fixing the lines manually here (and forgetting crucial stuff...). The syntax for `fun2` was correct as it is, however there was a mistake for `val=...` in the objective function. I `Apply` the target function to the list of parameters. To see why, evaluate `f@@{a,b,c}`.

Comment: Okay. One last weird behaviour: if `fun2` is just the sum of the inputs, why in your third and fourth example is the value never the sum of the inputs?

Comment: @Ziofil Because the last square bracket of the `If` statement was not supposed to close before the `tempVal=...` part. Corrected now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This would be perfect, except that in my case it kind of ignores the constraints.. For instance, check with `Circle[]` instead of `Disk[]`

Comment: Ooh I see why: `NMaximize`/`NMinimize` doesn't respect the constraints at every iteration, especially at the beginning. This leads `timedOptimization` to store a particularly good result that does not satisfy the constraints and then it's not able to beat it once the optimization routine becomes more respectful of the constraints later on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49242/discussion-between-ziofil-and-lukas).

Answer (score 9):

Each of the four methods in `NMinimize` has built-in hooks you can use to get the current values through `StepMonitor`.  There are some great advantages to this approach over ones that hijack the user's objective function and only minor drawbacks:

- The regular `NMinimize` interface can be used.
- The user's objective function will be used as is, so that any analysis of the function normally done by `NMinimize` is not prevented by wrapping the objective function in shell that turns the function into a numeric black box.
- The hooks give direct access to the state of the method algorithm being used. One could hardly ask for more.
- The hooks are easy to access.  Some post-processing is often needed, depending on the method.  One might want further to apply `FindMinimum[]` to the results (not shown).
- The hooks are undocumented AFAIK, and perhaps they are subject to change. OTOH, the code is open to inspection and this approach can be adapted should new methods be added or old methods improved.  I believe the current code has been stable for a fairly long time.

Note that `NMaximize[f[x], x]` basically calls `NMinimize[-f[x], x]`, so I will speak primarily in terms of minimization.  The raw values you get with the following approaches will also be of `-f[x]`, when using `NMaximize[]`.  In most examples below, which call `NMaximize[]`, this is accounted for that the maximum is returned.

In `NMinimize` the objective function consists of the user's function plus a penalty function.  There are two values that it keeps track of, `val` and `fval`. The value initially optimized is `val`, which equals `fval` plus a penalty (often `0.`), where `fval` is the value of the function.  At the end of the method, there is post-processing of the results, sometimes using the equivalent of `FindMinimum` to polish the results.

Each algorithm is different and there is not a uniform user-interface to them.  Here are examples of each:

**"DifferentialEvolution"**

In this example `foo` contains the most recent pools of points (`vecs`) and values.  One can use [linked lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/4999) to keep track of each step (see `"SimulatedAnnealing"` at the end).

```
(*  "DifferentialEvolution"  *)
TimeConstrained[
 NMaximize[
  {7 x - 4 x^2 + y - y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]}, {x, y},
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", 
  StepMonitor :> 
   If[ValueQ@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`fvals, 
    foo = {Optimization`NMinimizeDump`vals, Optimization`NMinimizeDump`vecs, 
      Optimization`NMinimizeDump`fvals}]],
 0.1]

tolerance = 10^-7;
Last@ Sort@ Pick[Transpose[{-foo[[1]], Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ foo[[2]]}], 
   UnitStep[foo[[1]] - foo[[3]] - tolerance], 0]
(*
$Aborted
{3.31235, {x -> 0.870649, y -> 0.491204}}
*)
```

**"NelderMead"**

Like with `"DifferentialEvolution"`, `foo` contains the most recent pools of points (`vecs`, the "simplex") and values.

```
(*  "NelderMead"  *)
TimeConstrained[
 NMaximize[
  {7 x - 4 x^2 + y - y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]}, {x, y},
  Method -> {"NelderMead",
    "RandomSeed" -> 1 (* for reproducibility *)}, 
  StepMonitor :> 
   If[ValueQ@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`fvals, 
    foo = {Optimization`NMinimizeDump`vals, Optimization`NMinimizeDump`vecs, 
      Optimization`NMinimizeDump`fvals}]],
 0.05]

tolerance = 10^-7;
Last@ Sort@ Pick[Transpose[{-foo[[1]], Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ foo[[2]]}], 
   UnitStep[tolerance + foo[[3]] - foo[[1]]], 1]
(*
$Aborted
{3.31236, {x -> 0.871075, y -> 0.491156}}
*)
```

Note that each value `val` has a penalty.  Hence the need for a positive `tolerance`, or all points would be rejected.  (This would be cleaned up in post-processing, which was aborted by the time constraint.)  As one can see below, the selected point above does not satisfy `{x, y} ∈ Disk[]`.  The user will have to decide how to treat the results in their particular case. (This applies to all methods, in fact.)

```
Norm[{x, y}] /. Last[%] // InputForm
(*  1.0000027734542223  *)

foo[[1]] - foo[[3]]
(*  {5.21808*10^-8, 3.6511*10^-8, 5.48056*10^-8}  *)
```

**"RandomSearch"**

In `"RandomSearch"` `results` is initialized to the pool of initial points.  Each point is replaced by the result of a local minimizer (which may be specified  with the `"Method"` suboption to `Method`).  The post-processing code chooses the best result of the minimizer.

```
(*  "RandomSearch"  *)
TimeConstrained[
 NMaximize[{7 x - 4 x^2 + y - y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> "RandomSearch", 
  StepMonitor :> 
   If[ValueQ@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`results, 
    foo = Optimization`NMinimizeDump`results]],
 0.2]
Select[foo, ! FreeQ[#, "Converged"] &]
(*
$Aborted
{{{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}},
 {{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}},
 {{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}},
 {{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}},
 {{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}},
 {{-3.31236, {0.871072 -> 0.871072, 0.491155 -> 0.491155}}, {True, "Converged"}}}
*)
```

**"SimulatedAnnealing"**

Simulated annealing works somewhat like the random search method in that it starts with a pool of initial points and processes each individually.  It then does some post-processing and returns the best result found.  As it processes each point, it keeps track of the best result of processing that point in the form

```
 Optimization`NMinimizeDump`best = {val, vec, fval}
```

To accumulate all the results efficiently, I used [link lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/4999). I wrapped the list `` Optimization`NMinimizeDump`best `` in an undefined head called `hold` to make flattening the linked list in post-processing easier.  Note it does **not** [`Hold[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) the results.

```
(*  "SimulatedAnnealing"  *)
TimeConstrained[
 ClearAll[hold];
 foo = {};
 NMaximize[{7 x - 4 x^2 + y - y^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]}, {x, y}, 
  Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", 
  StepMonitor :> 
   If[ValueQ@Optimization`NMinimizeDump`best, 
    foo = {hold[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`best], foo}]],
 0.02]
foo = Flatten@foo /. hold -> Identity;

tolerance = 0;
First@ Sort@ Pick[
   Transpose[{-foo[[All, 1]], Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ foo[[All, 2]]}], 
   UnitStep[tolerance + foo[[All, 3]] - foo[[All, 1]]], 1]
(*
$Aborted
{3.25174, {x -> 0.753606, y -> 0.457427}}
*)
```

Comment: I ended using the other solution, but I'm also playing around with your code.  At the moment, for some reason, `foo` is not assigned a value when I use my objective function. I'll keep playing.

Comment: @Ziofil Can you tell me the function? Or you might try `StepMonitor` without the `If[ValueQ@..,` part.  `NMinimize` does one symbolic evaluation for some reason, which messed up the post-processing.  If `foo` is not assigned a value, it seems to imply `StepMonitor` is not evaluated.