# Why does Sow appear to miss many function calls in my code

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization, monitoring

I encountered this problem while addressing an answer to [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132238/time-constrained-optimization).

Here I do the following:

I ask `NMaximize` to do its job, and I use `Reap` and `Sow` with `EvaluationMonitor` to store the values that it tried in the list called  `reapSowPoints`. At the same time, the objective function also stores the variables that were called in a separate list called `functionCalls`. These two lists should be the same, but they are actually very different. Why is that?

Here's the code:

```
myMaximization[vars_, objective_] := 
  Reap[
    Module[{customFunction},
      customFunction[v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ]] := 
        Module[{val = objective @@ v}, 
          AppendTo[functionCalls, v]; 
          val];
        NMaximize[
          {customFunction[vars], Norm @ vars == 1}, 
          vars, 
          EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[vars]]]]
```

When I evaluate it I obtain (e.g.):

```
functionCalls = {};
{result, reapSowPoints} = myMaximization[{x, y}, #1 + #2 &];
Length /@ {functionCalls, reapSowPoints[[1]]}
```

> `{1603, 222}`

The function was called 1603 times, but `Sow` appears to have caught only 222 of them.

Comment: Please check the spelling and usage of `Sow` versus `Saw`.

Comment: Also consider `Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ {functionCalls, First@reapSowPoints}`.  It's more a problem with `EvaluationMonitor` than with `Sow`.

Comment: Strange, I get more function evaluations with fewer iterations (`MaxIterations -> 10`) than with more (`MaxIterations -> 100`).

Comment: I think the discrepancy has to do with post-processing the `NMaximize[]` routine.  The `EvaluationMonitor` is not used in this phase, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy is probably accounted for in post-processing the initial optimization routine.  I couldn't check this without specifying an explicit method and post-processor.

```
myMaximization[vars_, objective_] := 
 Reap[Module[{customFunction}, 
   customFunction[v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ]] := 
    Module[{val = objective @@ v},
     AppendTo[functionCalls, v];
     val];
   NMaximize[{customFunction[vars], Norm@vars == 1}, vars, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[vars, "NMaximize"], MaxIterations -> 100,
     Method -> {Automatic, 
      "PostProcess" -> {"FindMinimum", 
        EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[vars, "FindMinimum"]}}]],
  _,
  Rule]

functionCalls = {};
{result, reapSowPoints} = myMaximization[{x, y}, #1 + #2 &];
Length /@ {functionCalls, #[[1]], #[[2]], Join @@ #} &[{"NMaximize", 
   "FindMinimum"} /. reapSowPoints]
Length /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ 
  {functionCalls, #[[1]], #[[2]], Join @@ #} &[{"NMaximize",
    "FindMinimum"} /. reapSowPoints]
(*      Fn calls  NMaximize  FindMinimum  NMaximize+FindMinimum
  raw: {  1556,     222,        1126,            1348}
  DD:  {   577,     213,         379,            578}
*)
```

There's still a discrepancy in the raw data, but after the duplicates are removed, the discrepancy disappears. Many of the duplicates are the symbolic expression `{x, y}`, which alternates with a numeric pair in the post-processing calls.  (I don't know why.)  The symbolic `{x, y}` is not included in `functionCalls` because of the pattern check `VectorQ[v, NumericQ]` on `customFunction[]`.

Comment: Good catch. Also, I verified that the extra point is a symbolic `{x, y}` pair, so all is good!